# Closure with callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok, here's a closure issue (i think) that I'm dealing with. Can't wrap my head around it. I have a component and I'm trying to get the updated value of `shouldDropAbove` into my callback `onStepItemDrop`:

```
export const StepItem = () => {
  const [shouldDropAbove, setShouldDropAbove] = React.useState<boolean>()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(shouldDropAbove) //outputs updated value correctly
  }, [shouldDropAbove])

  console.log(shouldDropAbove) //also is outputting the updated value correctly

  const onStepItemDrop = (draggingStep) => {
    console.log(shouldDropAbove) //outputting undefined ?????
  }

  return (
    <Droppable
      onDrop={onStepItemDrop}
      setShouldDropAbove={setShouldDropAbove} //Droppable updates setShouldDropAbove correctly
    >
      {jsx stuff}
    </Droppable>
  )
}
```

```
export const Droppable = ({onDrop, setShouldDropAbove}) => {
  //updating setShouldDropAbove
}
```

What is going on here and why can't I get the correct value in the callback?

Comment: On the first render `shouldDropAbove` is indeed `undefined` because you don't give it an initial value. But on successive renders it should log appropriately since the function will be redeclared on each render with the updated value.

Comment: This is what I thought as well. But it doesn't function that way for some reason.

Comment: You'll need to post a working example for more help

Comment: here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-scott-8y76b3?file=/src/App.js) showing the above described behavior